# zend framework 2 + phpunit + multiple modules + continuous integration

Tags: ant, jenkins, phpunit, zend-framework2

Thanks in advance for any comments. I have just started to switch from Zend Framework 1 to ZF2 and after running through the quick start and several other tutorials I noticed that there is a short coming with the 'default' way to use phpunit. Either that or I am just lost and confused.

The folder structure for a default project is

```
Project
| - config
| | - autoload
| | | - global.php
| | | - local.php.dist
| | - application.config.php
| - data
| - module
| | - Application
| | | - config
| | | - src
| | | - test
| | | | - ApplicationTest
| | | | - Bootstrap.php
| | | | - phpunit.xml
| | | | - TestConfig.php.dist 
| | | - view
| | | - Module.php
| | - Album
| | | - config
| | | - src
| | | - test
| | | | - AlbumTest
| | | | - Bootstrap.php
| | | | - phpunit.xml
| | | | - TestConfig.php.dist 
| | | - view
| | | - Module.php
| - public
| - vendor
```

My question is this how do I use Jenkins with ANT to test all of the phpunit test suites.  I understand the reason behind testing each module individually but how can I properly automate that to get one report.xml back.  And it would be even better if I didn't need to specify each module in a phpunit config. or the build.xml.

Again thank you for any comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I forgot to answer my own question when I figured it out I apologize to the community that I forgot... but for everyones benefit here is how I got it to work.

build.xml

```
<target name="phpunit" description="Run unit tests with PHPUnit">
    <apply executable="../vendor/bin/phpunit" parallel="false">
        <fileset dir="${env.WORKSPACE}/module" >
            <include name="**/test/phpunit.xml"/>
        </fileset>
        <arg value="--configuration" />
        <srcfile/>
    </apply>
</target>
```

And the phpunit.xml for each module

```
<phpunit bootstrap="Bootstrap.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application">
            <directory>./</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

<!-- Filters only matter for code coverage reporting -->
    <filter>
        <blacklist>
            <directory>../../../vendor/</directory>
            <directory>./</directory>
            <file>../Module.php</file>
        </blacklist>
    </filter>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="../../../build/coverage" title="Application Module" charset="UTF-8" yui="true" highlight="true" lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="../../../build/logs/clover-Application.xml"/>
        <log type="junit" target="../../../build/logs/junit-Application.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I use the following structure. I have all tests inside tests folder and I structure the tests in the same way as modules are structured:

```
Project
| - config
| | - autoload
| | | - global.php
| | | - local.php.dist
| | - application.config.php
| - data
| - module
| | - Application
| | | - config
| | | - src
| | | | - Application
| | | | | - Controller
| | | | | | - IndexController.php
| | | | | - Model
| | | | | | - Foo.php
| | | | | - Form
| | | - view
| | | - Module.php
| | - Album
| | | - config
| | | - src
| | | | - Album
| | | | | - Controller
| | | | | | - IndexController.php
| | | | | - Model
| | | | | | - Bar.php
| | | | | - Form
| | | - view
| | | - Module.php
| - public
| - vendor
| - tests
| | - unit
| | | - module
| | | | - Application
| | | | | - src
| | | | | | - Application
| | | | | | | - Controller
| | | | | | | | - IndexControllerTest.php
| | | | | | | - Model
| | | | | | | | - FooTest.php
| | | | - Album
| | | | | - src
| | | | | | - Album
| | | | | | | - Controller
| | | | | | | | - IndexControllerTest.php
| | | | | | | - Model
| | | | | | | | - BarTest.php
| | - functional
| | | - features
| - phpunit.xml
| - phpunit-ci.xml
| - behat.yml
```

PHPUnit configs can look something like this (simplified example, add whitelist, filters, coverage etc according to your needs):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="tests/unit/Bootstrap.php" colors="true" backupGlobals="false" backupStaticAttributes="false" syntaxCheck="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="sites">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">tests/unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Example of phpunit-ci.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="tests/unit/Bootstrap.php" colors="true" backupGlobals="false" backupStaticAttributes="false" syntaxCheck="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="sites">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">tests/unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist>    
            <!-- Album module -->
            <directory suffix=".php">module/Album/src/Album/Model</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">module/Album/src/Album/Controller</directory>

            <!-- Application module -->
            <directory suffix=".php">module/Application/src/Application/Model</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">module/Application/src/Application/Controller</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="build/coverage" charset="UTF-8"
             yui="true" highlight="true" lowUpperBound="40" highLowerBound="80" />
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="build/logs/clover.xml" />
        <log type="junit" target="build/logs/junit.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false" />
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

In build.xml it's easy:

```
<target name="phpunit-ci" description="Run unit tests with config file for CI">
    <sequential>

        <exec executable="${basedir}/vendor/bin/phpunit" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="--version" />
        </exec>

        <exec executable="${basedir}/vendor/bin/phpunit" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="-c" />
            <arg path="${basedir}/phpunit-ci.xml" />
        </exec>

    </sequential>
</target>
```