# run all zend framework2 unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, phpunit, zend-framework2

I'm trying to get a project build setup in Jenkins for Zend Framework 2, I want to run all the unit tests for each of the modules I am writing - but I'm a lil unclear how to do this?

Each module has its own 'test' directory and I can run each modules test suite just fine.  Do I have to write some script to find all custom modules and run their tests?  Does anyone have a good example how to do this?

Comment: Check out my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628427/zend-framework-2-phpunit-multiple-modules-continuous-integration?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

**First, get the test to run together**

I would try writing a new phpunit config file, say all.xml, giving the details of the different test files.

```
 <phpunit>
     <testsuite name="Module1">
          <directory>./module1</directory>
     </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="Module2">
          <directory>./module2</directory>
     </testsuite>
     <testsuite name="Module2">
          <directory>./module3</directory>
     </testsuite>
</phpunit>
```

Test that this runs ok on the command line

```
$ phpunit -c all.xml
```

**Add to Jenkins**

Just add this into you Jenkins config. Here is an example if you use an Ant xml file:

```
<target name="phpunit" description="Run unit tests with PHPUnit">
    <exec executable="phpunit" failonerror="true">
        <arg line=" -c tests/all.xml" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: Maybe anyone knows how to add bootstraps to each testsuite using this structure?

Comment: I'm starting to try out Jenkins, does it automatically deploy to NGinx or is that configured somehow in ANT?  I see no mention of this in the PHP+Jenkin template tutorials so far.