# How to test every module in my application phpunit - zend framework 2

Tags: php, testing, jenkins, zend-framework2, phpunit

I already made test for my application module and other module. They are working fine but i want to run all the test (application module and other module) toguether to generate clover report for jenkins. What should i do?? create another config file to invoke other config files??

---edit---

I have the same code for each module bootstrap.php  and i want to use the same for each module to avoid code duplication. Rigth now i have two modules Application and Problem when i run phpunit it throws me this error:

```
**.PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ProblemTest\Bootstrap' not found ....**
```

The test for the Application module works fine but the test for Problem module doesn't work for the namespace declaration in the **phpunit_bootstrap.php** file.

My Application test uses this declaration:

```
<?php
   namespace ApplicationTest\Controller;
   use ApplicationTest\Bootstrap; ....
```

My Problem tes uses this declaration:

```
<?php
    namespace ProblemTest\Controller;
    use ProblemTest\Bootstrap;
```

This is my phpunit.xml

```
<phpunit bootstrap="phpunit_bootstrap.php">
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="ALL">
        <directory>module/Application/test</directory>
        <directory>module/Problem/test</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

this is my phpunit_bootstrap.php

```
<?php
 namespace ApplicationTest;
```

The problem that i have rigth now to run all the test toguether is how to include the same bootstrap for every test to avoid that exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment yet so another solution to this issue can be found at [zend framework 2 + phpunit + multiple modules + continuous integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628427/zend-framework-2-phpunit-multiple-modules-continuous-integration/24134625#24134625) If you don't want to go through naming each module independently.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a testsuite to run a bunch of individual groups of tests all at once. In your phpunit.xml.dist file:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="phpunit_bootstrap.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="all">
            <directory>./</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="ALL">
            <directory>/path/to/module1tests</directory>
            <directory>/path/to/module2tests</directory>
            <directory>/path/to/module3tests</directory>
            <exclude>/path/to/module4tests</exclude>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="module1only">
            <directory>./module1tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
```

And then you can run it with: /path/to/phpunit --testsuite="ALL"

Comment: There is a way to setup a bootstrap for each module??

Comment: @user1835922: yes by specifying the bootstrap file with the testrunner not inside the XML file.