# How to deal with unit-tests in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework2, phpunit

I have a Zend-Framework 2 Project and i have problems to organize my unit-tests. My unit-test are located in one "test"-folder for each module. If I run the test from the command line with phpunit in the test folder of a module, the test will run successfully.

Example:

c:\project\module\AccessControl\test>phpunit

```
PHPUnit 3.7.14 by Sebastian Bergmann.
Configuration read from c:\project\module\AccessControl\test\phpunit.xml
........Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 8.25Mb
OK (8 tests, 10 assertions)
```

**Problem**: Here only one module will be testet. But I want to run a single testsuite from the folder c:\project\ to test the hole project.
There I have put a bootstrap.php and a phpunit.xml.

From the command line I run it with:

C:\project\tests>phpunit --debug --configuration phpunit.xml

```
PHPUnit 3.7.14 by Sebastian Bergmann.
Configuration read from C:\project\tests\phpunit.xml
Starting test 'AccessControlTest\Model\AuthenticationTest::testInitDefault'.
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'AccessControlTest\Bootstrap' not found in C:\project\module\AccessControl\test\AccessControlTest\Model\AuthenticationTest.php on line 22
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\phpunit:46
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:129
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:176
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner.php:346
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:705
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->runTest() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:745
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:775
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php:769
PHP  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult.php:648
PHP  11. AccessControlTest\Model\AuthenticationTest->setUp() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php:821
```

The file phpunit.xml looks like this:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./Bootstrap.php" colors="true" verbose="true">
 <testsuite name="SgtrCatalogTestsuite">
  <directory>../module/AccessControl</directory>
 </testsuite>
</phpunit>
```

It looks like some modulepaths are not correct. Can somebody help and tell me how to setup this?

**EDIT**
Ty for your replys!!!

In the meantime i found this:
[How to consolidate ZF2 unit/application module tests into a single call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860702/how-to-consolidate-zf2-unit-application-module-tests-into-a-single-call?rq=1)

It seems not possible to run all module-tests from rootlevel. I try now to use this and let u know if it works: https://github.com/prolic/HumusPHPUnitModule

Comment: Do you have autoload in your composer.json?

Comment: What does your Bootstrap.php look like?

Comment: ty, autoloader is there ... i edit the question because i found a possible duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this section in your composer.json

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "AccessControlTest\\": "tests/",
            "AccessControl\\": "src/module/AccessControl/src/"
        }
    }
```

And then run

```
$ php composer.phar dump-autoload
```

Comment: We try this but it dont work for us. We found a Solution for the problem. I make an Edit, thank you